# Display cursor and text both in textbox when page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on Asp.net MVC.

i am using regular html

```
  <label for="txtbox1" > User Name</label>
<input type="text" id="txtbox1" name="text" class="water"/>
```

I want to display Cursor before text and Text both when page load. When user start writting in text box at that time "User Name" removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use javascript for this. If you are using jquery you could:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtbox1').focus();
});
```

And if you want to do this with plain javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var textbox = document.getElementById('txtbox1');
    if (textbox != null) {
        textbox.focus();
    }
};
```

---

UPDATE:

If you want the text to disappear when the user starts typing you may try the following:

```
$('#txtbox1').keypress(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('dirty')) {
        $(this).val('').data('dirty', true);
    }
});
```

[Live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/xNREH/)

Comment: I want to display BOTH.. This display only Cursor not text.

Comment: @Mvcdev, what text? The textbox already displays the `value` attribute. Also note that there is no `visible` attribute to an input tag.

Comment: @Drain  I am sorry for little confusion.I Changed my code now.I want to dispaly cursor and User Name both in Textbox when page load. When user start write their user name at that time "User Name" Go away.

Comment: @Mvcdev, you want to display a watermark? You could either use a [jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) or HTML5 [placeholder attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder).

Comment: @Drain, Watermark is also display text but as soon as i click on textbox that text gose away. And i want text go away when user press key from keyboard.

Comment: @Darin  Thanks for your help... I appreciate for your hard work and giving me LIVE Demo.. Thanks Again.

Comment: Hey @drain Is that any way you can add in live demo how to display Cursor too. If you can. Again Thanks for your help !!!!!!!